# Unexpected __source property in compiled JSX

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have a weird problem. When I try to compile React code with Babel 6, the JSX code is compiled with references to the source file. Here is my setup. I installed babel-cli globally, then I also installed babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-react. Finally, I updated the .babelrc to reference these presets, like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

and I added a build script to my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel assets/scripts/main.jsx --out-file assets/scripts/main.js"
  }
}
```

But when I run the build script. something weird happens. Here is a part of the source script which is actually from React's tutorial:

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass ({

   handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = this.refs.author.value.trim();
    var text = this.refs.text.value.trim();
    if (!text || !author) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
    this.refs.author.value = '';
    this.refs.text.value = '';
    return;
  },

   render: function() {
      return (
         <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author" />
           <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." ref="text" />
           <input type="submit" value="Post" />
         </form>
      );
   }
});


ReactDOM.render(
   <CommentBox url="test.json" pollInterval={2000} />,
   document.getElementById('content')
);
```

When I run the build script, I get this compiled code for this snippet:

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
   displayName: 'CommentForm',

   handleSubmit: function handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var author = this.refs.author.value.trim();
      var text = this.refs.text.value.trim();
      if (!text || !author) {
         return;
      }
      this.props.onCommentSubmit({ author: author, text: text });
      this.refs.author.value = '';
      this.refs.text.value = '';
      return;
   },

   render: function render() {
      return React.createElement(
         'form',
         { className: 'commentForm', onSubmit: this.handleSubmit, __source: {
               fileName: '../../../assets/scripts/main.jsx',
               lineNumber: 105
            }
         },
         React.createElement('input', { type: 'text', placeholder: 'Your name', ref: 'author', __source: {
               fileName: '../../../assets/scripts/main.jsx',
               lineNumber: 106
            }
         }),
         React.createElement('input', { type: 'text', placeholder: 'Say something...', ref: 'text', __source: {
               fileName: '../../../assets/scripts/main.jsx',
               lineNumber: 107
            }
         }),
         React.createElement('input', { type: 'submit', value: 'Post', __source: {
               fileName: '../../../assets/scripts/main.jsx',
               lineNumber: 108
            }
         })
      );
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(CommentBox, { url: 'test.json', pollInterval: 2000, __source: {
      fileName: '../../../assets/scripts/main.jsx',
      lineNumber: 116
   }
}), document.getElementById('content'));
```

As you can see, the compiled script actually contains references back to the source file for the JSX code. JSX doesn't compile properly to Javascript.

It seems like I am doing everything right, and there is no error when compiling the code, yet the JSX is not compiled properly. What am I doing wrong? Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__source` [has been added](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/4596) as special property to React. [This is the Babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source) that adds this property automatically.

This seems to have been done to improve debugging information. The transform adds those automatically, but they should not appear in production builds.

See [the documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#env-option) how to specify the environment:

> You can use the env option to set specific options when in a certain environment:
>
> ```
> {
>   "env": {
>     "production": {
>       "plugins": ["transform-react-constant-elements"]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The env `key` will be taken from `process.env.BABEL_ENV`, when this is not available then it uses `process.env.NODE_ENV` if even that is not available then it defaults to `"development"`.
>
> You can set this environment variable with the following:
>
> Unix
>
> ```
> # at the start of a command
> $ BABEL_ENV=production YOUR_COMMAND_HERE
>
> # or as a separate command
> $ NODE_ENV=production
> $ YOUR_COMMAND_HERE
> ```
>
> Windows
>
> ```
> $ SET BABEL_ENV=production
> $ YOUR_COMMAND_HERE
> ```

---

> It seems like I am doing everything right, and there is no error when compiling the code, yet the JSX is not compiled properly.

Not sure why you think it is not compiled properly, it is.

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling! It makes total sense. I actually compiled the same code on the Babel website (their compiler still uses Babel 5), and when I compared the two, I thought something was wrong with my setup.